# Mod_Rewrite on Query String in WordPress installation

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm trying to create a simple booking form. The are four options on a separate page (group, corporate, student and venue).

For example: If the user clicks Book Now for Group Experience it should take them to a dynamic page containing the form with the query string 'Group-Experience'. This query string will be used for the value of the subject field.

Now the problem, At the moment this is what I have:

**URL:** `/book/?menu=group-experience`
**subject field:** "group-experience".

I would like:

**URL:** `/book/group-experience`
**subject field:** "Group Experience"

I've got it so the `-` is removed with:

```
<?php
$menu = str_replace ( "-", " ", $_GET['menu']);
?>
```

I've looked around StackOverflow and other websites but can't find a method that works alongside WordPress - The form is inside a template file.

My current `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /lab/foodfiendexp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /lab/foodfiendexp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add a page rewrite rule, to do that add the following code to functions.php

```
add_filter( 'page_rewrite_rules', 'book_page_rewrite_rules' );
function book_page_rewrite_rules( $rewrite_rules )
{
    end( $rewrite_rules );
    $last_pattern = key( $rewrite_rules );
    $last_replacement = array_pop( $rewrite_rules );
    $rewrite_rules +=  array(
        '(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&menu=$matches[2]',
        $last_pattern => $last_replacement,
    );
    return $rewrite_rules;
}

add_rewrite_tag('%menu%','([^&]+)');
```

Then update the permalink structure from Settings -> Permalinks, you just hit save again.

And you access your menu with

```
$menu = get_query_var('menu');
```

Now you url should work with

```
/book/group-experience
```

considering book is a page, if you need to add the rewrite rule to a post, change it to a post rewrite rule

More details here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Also, if you need an rewrite rule inspector, this plugin is very very good: http://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/